# Why $ F(u_\gamma) = \int_{\Omega} | \nabla u (D \tau_{\gamma})^{-1} |^2 \det (D \tau_\gamma) ?$ Is this by change of variables?

Tags: calculus, analysis

I'd like to understand the following: Let 
\begin{equation}
F(u) = \int_{\Omega } |\nabla u|^2 
\end{equation}
where $ \Omega $ is adomain in $ \mathbb{R}^{n} \cdots $
For $ | \gamma | $ small enough define $ \tau_\gamma \Omega \rightarrow \Omega $ by $ \tau_\gamma (x)= x +\gamma \psi(x) $ where $ \psi \in C^\infty_0 (\Omega,\mathbb{R}^n) $. Setting $ u_\gamma = u \circ \tau_{\gamma}^{-1} $ Why
\begin{equation}
F(u_\gamma) = \int_\Omega | \nabla u (D \tau_{\gamma})^{-1} |^2 \det (D \tau_\gamma) ?
\end{equation}

I believe that this follows by the change of variables. If $ G: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism 
\begin{equation}
\int_{G(\Omega)} f = \int_\Omega  f \circ G | \det D_x G|
\end{equation}
but I don't get the calculations.

The motivation for this is to undertand the theorem 5.2 in this article [here](http://www.springerlink.com/content/jr753175003k1724/fulltext.pdf). By the way if you explain the details in the proof of the thorem above I will be very grateful.

Comment: What is $G$ in the last displayed equation?

Comment: Shouldn't it read $u_\gamma = u \circ \tau_\gamma^{-1}$ instead of $\tau_{\gamma^{-1}}$?

Comment: Sorry David Giraudo I forgot to say What is $G$? You can ask another thing you want.

Comment: Yes Martini, I did a typo.

Comment: The link to the paper at `springerlink.com` seems to be broken. Perhaps you could take a look, whenever possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}$I don't have access to the linked article, but we have
\begin{align*}
  F(u_\gamma) &= F(u \circ \tau_\gamma^{-1})\\
        &= \int_\Omega \abs{\nabla(u \circ \tau_\gamma^{-1})}^2\\
        &= \int_\Omega \abs{(\nabla u) \circ \tau_\gamma^{-1} \cdot D\tau_\gamma^{-1}}^2\\
        &= \int_{\tau_\gamma^{-1}\Omega} \abs{(\nabla u) \circ \tau_\gamma^{-1}\circ \tau_\gamma\cdot D\tau_\gamma^{-1}\circ \tau_\gamma}^2\abs{\det(D\tau_\gamma)}\\
        &= \int_\Omega \abs{\nabla u\cdot (D\tau_\gamma)^{-1}}^2\abs{\det(D\tau_\gamma)}
\end{align*}
If $\gamma$ is small, $\det(D\tau_\gamma)$ will be positive, as $\det$ is continuous and $D\tau_0 = \mathrm{id}$, so 
\[ F(u_\gamma) = \int_\Omega \abs{\nabla u\cdot (D\tau_\gamma)^{-1}}^2\det(D\tau_\gamma)\]

Comment: Very good. Could you give me a referece or to say How can I obtain $ \nabla (u \circ \tau_{\gamma}^{-1}) = (\nabla u) \circ \tau_{\gamma}^{-1} \cdot D \tau_{\gamma}^{-1}$. I will be happy in accept your answer.

Comment: It's the chain rule ... componentwise we have (writing $\tau$ for $\tau_\gamma^{-1}$) \\[ \partial_i(u \circ \tau) = \sum_j (\partial_j u)\circ \tau \cdot \partial_i\tau_j \\] right? Combine these equations to get $\nabla(u \circ \tau) = (\nabla u)\circ \tau \cdot D\tau$.

Comment: I put what I do not get it here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229941/why-fu-gamma-int-omega-nabla-u-d-tau-gamma-1-det-d